# Google Graph API Custom Tooltip Bolding

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to replicate the default tooltip styling used by the Google Graph API:

[image: Default Tooltip]

In particular the bolding of some of the text as seen above. As soon as I add my own tooltip I can no longer bold parts of the text as in the default view.

The label `tooltip.textStyle` only offers one the option of changing the colour for the entire text displayed `{color: <string>, fontName: <string>, fontSize: <number>}`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default view is styled with the bold, while custom tooltips are not.

Depending on your chart type, you can enable HTML tooltips and use those to customize the format as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#enabling_html_tooltip). This will work for:

- AreaChart
- BarChart
- CandlestickChart
- ColumnChart
- ComboChart
- LineChart
- ScatterChart

It is complicated to set up, but it will allow you maximum flexibility in how your tooltips are displayed.

Comment: Not really that complicated to setup - I was halfway there in any case. Works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to: @jmac answer, it's easy. But if you can't bold font (according with Google Charts Docs) please set custom font-family, ex.:

```
function createCustomHTMLContent(date, label, value) {
return '<div style=" font-family:Arial; /* other styles... */">' +
        '<div><b>' + date + '</b></div>'+
        '<div><b>' + label + ':</b> ' + value + ' </div>'+
    ' </div>'
}
```

I can't found any solutions for a long while, and after set font-family propeteries everything works :)